# How can I pass command line arguments when activating a conda environment in a shell script

Tags: arguments, conda, environment

I am on Linux, Python 3.6. 
I have a shell script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

instance=$1 
export instance
echo "Instance is" $instance 

. /home/xyz/setenvvars.sh
source activate myenv 
echo arg1 $1 
echo env  $instance 
python myprg.py $1 
python myprg.py $instance
```

It seems after I activate the conda environment, the command line argument this shell script received is not available in the activated environment. How can I pass the command line argument this script originally received to newly activated environment. The 2 echos after the activate show blanks.

TIA!

Comment: What does `/home/xyz/setenvvars.sh`?

Comment: It sets PATH to find conda

Comment: And does your environment do anything fancy upon activation? What version of conda are you using? Also, please provide a fully working version of the script, and exact input and output.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but [Snakemake seems to get away with](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/src/e049f5e49635ff9c56544a7b1efb5e1a193e1530/snakemake/conda.py#lines-358) `source activate 'env_path'; cmd` where `cmd` is an arbitrarily long string of commands, but all values I think are literal in there.  That is the args are already evaluated in the string (no longer `$1` etc.).

Comment: @FabienP  - I'm not doing anything special in the conda env activation other than  the stock behavior.

Comment: @merv - I need to pass a command line argument to this shell script. The argument needs to be available to the python program called in the shell script. Essentially $1 or $instance is not available on the last two lines of the script. I need to pass whatever I get as argument to this script down to the python program on the last two lines.

Comment: @enem I cannot replicate this behaviour, if I create a similar script it works as expected. However, I have to make assumptions on how you set PATH to find conda, and on what your env does upon activation. What would help is the content of `setenvvars.sh`, and of `<path_to_myenv>/conda/activate.d/*.sh` if any.